# Python Selenium - Source from href link

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to be able to get the source page of the link I got from a *a href* without making Selenium changing page.

I am getting the *a* element using

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class, 'css-1xyedec e1pf1lj70')]")
```

Then I can get the link in the href using

```
elem.get_attribute('href')
```

But I cannot find a way to get the source page of the link using selenium without changing the page of the browser.

EDIT: [Here](https://www.leboncoin.fr/voitures/offres) is the website on which I am trying to do it. The *<a>* is located for each sale in each *div* that includes the photo and the part with the title, price...

Comment: You could open a new tab with that link and than use driver.page_source the close it.

Comment: This class seems to be dynamic: `e1pf1lj70`. Add html cod please.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I will maybe do like this if there is no better solution.

Comment: after you get href of the page try to get HTML with requests library if it's not dynamic
`html = requests.get(url)`

Comment: @GiorgiImerlishvili The problem is I cannot use requests because the website detect it and ask me to solve a Captcha. I bypass the Captcha with Selenium by solving it once and then saving my cookies and reusing them with Selenium.

Comment: @Mickaël so just open new tab and extract HTML so.

Comment: @GiorgiImerlishvili as I answered to ArundeepChohan above, I will do this way, I was just hoping to another solution where I could get the source code without having to open another tab (which is visible for the user).

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17022/how-to-fill-captcha-using-test-automation .
You cannot automate captcha. You should ask dev team for a workaround.
I would ask to disable CAPTCHA in test environment. It is no sense to have it there.

Comment: I did managed to bypass the captcha using selenium and keeping cookies from one session to another. It is working quite good but pour limit on my work because for example I couldn't do the same with requests. I cannot ask the Dev team, I am not working for them, I am trying to collect data from the sales.

Comment: Ok, I wish you find the answer. Please post it if you will find it by yourself.